# How to create websocket server running inside Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, websocket, real-time

I want to create an app for some simple multiplayer game but I don't know how to create websocket server in Flutter. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [SocketServer class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-io/ServerSocket-class.html) (TCP). I have used this for a similar problem.

For a more complete answer, take a look at:
[Using Flutter App to run SocketServer and communicate with other phone via Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60397701/using-flutter-app-to-run-socketserver-and-communicate-with-other-phone-via-socke)

Answer (score -5):

flutter has got it covered in a very decent manner in its documentation check out
[here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/web-sockets)

Comment: The docs covered only connecting to a websocket server not creating it.