# sunmi v2 pro flutter binding from other device

Tags: android, flutter, sunmi

i looking for guide (**documentation**) for sunmi to binding/connect from other device ( android ) to my sunmi v2 pro to get a print ( bluetooth or wireless ).

in this case i dont know sunmi v2 pro is support print by wireless or not. i only found package thats only binding on built-in by its self device ( sunmi ) and works.

what i have tested

1. **sunmi_cloud_printer** its error printer not specify.
2. **sunmi_printer_plus** its only work with self device ( sunmi ) built in to get it connect / binding.

**expected**: other device connect to sunmi v2 pro. other device sent a command print to sunmi.

```
➜  ~ flutter --version

┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ A new version of Flutter is available!                  │
│                                                         │
│ To update to the latest version, run "flutter upgrade". │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Flutter 3.0.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f1875d570e (11 months ago) • 2022-07-13 11:24:16 -0700
Engine • revision e85ea0e79c
Tools • Dart 2.17.6 • DevTools 2.12.2
```

i have thinking about firebase notification thats for **trigger/webhook** or command to get my sunmi working ( to print ) its my tricky to handle or remote my sunmi device . but i looking for others. this my last choice if i dont get any guide i use fcm integrations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use websocket to send the print value from device to sunmi and then print it

Comment: yes `web_socket_channel` thankyou to remember me about thats, i think its more great for small area. but i still need to know is sunmi v2 pro support by wireless print or not. Today i am going to try with websocket.

Comment: just let me know and thanks to use my package =)

Comment: yes your welcome and just FYI for anyone else here is ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60397701/using-flutter-app-to-run-socketserver-and-communicate-with-other-phone-via-socke ) i work now with websocket thats great to handle this solution.